# Error: XMLHTTPRequest Failed... Why?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, parse-platform

I have two forms on my website. They both take email addresses and the code for both is the same. The first form works fine, but I'm getting an XMLHTTPRequest Failed error on the second. Why is this?

Here's the error:

```
Could not accept email address: XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}
```

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<section class="subscribe2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="subinput" placeholder="Enter your email for updates" spellcheck="false">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Subscribe now
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(".button-large").click(function() {
    console.log("Notify Me");

    var emailAdd = $(".input").val();

    if (emailAdd.length <5) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
    } else {
        var Address = $(".input").val();
        var Email = Parse.Object.extend("Email");
        var email = new Email();

        email.set("Address", Address);

        console.log(Address);

        email.save(null, {
            success: function(email) {
                console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + email.id);
            },
            error: function(email, error) {
                console.log('Could not accept email address: ' + error.message);
                alert("Error")
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show the forms here and what's the exact error?

Comment: what does the logged `error.message` say

Comment: updated with error and html

Comment: Have you tried to reference the inputs by id or name, instead of class

Comment: @hex494D49 yes, I still get the same error

Comment: Just a thought, are you trying to save different emails or the same one on both forms; 'cause I don't know that's this Email object, how it works inside. The forms are not nested I guess.

Comment: @hex494D49 I'm not quite sure I understand, but the forms are for a visitor to subscribe for email updates. They can either submit their address in the first form or the second form.